# Query para busca com várias tabelas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

preciso buscar os dados de uma tabela de processos, e de outras 2 tabelas uma de autores e réus do processo, a dúvida é como buscar de forma agrupada que eu possa percorrer com foreach para preencher um relatório, estou usando o Laravel, segue relação das tabelas e como deve ficar no relatório.

```
$processos = Processo::join('autores', 'autores.processo_id', 'processos.id')
        ->join('reus', 'reus.processo_id', 'processos.id')
        ->join('pessoas', 'autores.pessoa_id', 'pessoas.id')
        ->join('pessoas', 'reus.pessoa_id', 'pessoas.id')
        ->select('pessoas.nome as nome_pessoa', 'processos.*', 'autores.*', 'reus.*')->get();
```

Da esse erro: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: pessoas (SQL: select pessoas.nome as nome_pessoa, processos.*, autores.*, reus.* from processos inner join autores on processo.processo_id = processos.id inner join reus_processo on reus.processo_id = processos.id inner join pessoas on autores.pessoa_id = pessoas.id inner join pessoas on reus.pessoa_id = pessoas.id)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o código das classes também.

Comment: Que classe? você diz o controller?

Comment: Não, suas classes de modelo: `Processo`, `Pessoas`, `Reus` e `Autores`

Comment: A sua tabela tem data, mas, seus modelo de banco não tem! talvez você precise carregas as informações e depois uni-las de acordo com um critério, só resultado de banco nesses relacionamentos me parece bem complicado, pelo menos eu acho...

Comment: Utilizando os conceitos de ORM do Laravel você poderá atingir o objetivo.
Veja este exemplo.
https://github.com/GeekSilva97/laravel-orm

Answer (score 0):

Antes de implementar no Laravel é necessário compreender um pouco mais sobre os relacionamentos em banco de dados.

Na relação Processos-Réus e Processos-Autores você tem relacionamento N:N, portanto seria necessário criar uma tabela intermediária, como processos_reus e processos_autores.
Como exemplo, a tabela processos_reus teria os campos id, processo_id (estrangeira) e reu_id (estrangeira).

Segue um exemplo de migration:

```
Schema::create('processos_reus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('processo_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('reu_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('processo_id')->references('id')->on('processo');
        $table->foreign('reu_id')->references('id')->on('reus');
    });
```

Criadas as tabelas, você vai precisar fazer o relacionamento no Laravel para puxar as informações que você precisa em apenas uma variável. Você pode [ver um exemplo aqui](https://marcosmuniz.com.br/desenvolvimento-web/php/trabalhando-com-relacionamentos-many-to-many-no-laravel/).